# Get IP Address of client

Tags: development, javascript

I was wondering if it was possible to get the IP address of the client machine accessing a 2013 website. Is it possible to do this with an ajax call by utilizing one of the sharepoint RESTFUL services? Or do I need to manually make server side code to accomplish this.

Comment: could getting the ip through js will help ?

Comment: there is no way for javascript to get a client IP address without calling some external site. Which I do not want to do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript...............pls refer this. I guess u could use it.

Comment: try this one:http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/536040c4-e808-4f85-b811-df539ebe3a29/how-to-get-clientip-address-in-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious